# Why do some macaques have redder faces than others?

Tags: mammals, skin

I'm watching [Monkey Kingdom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3660770/), and I noticed some of the macaques have redder faces than others.

Specifically the females, and as the social ladder increases, so does the redness.

An alpha female:

[image: ALPHA MACAQUE]

Does the redness-hierarchy correlation have something to do with attractiveness or aggressiveness? (These seem to be leading factors in defining hierarchy otherwise.)

Comment: Aggressiveness, seems more likely, on first thought. Heightened Aggression, leading to stress, causing High blood pressure or an increase in vascularity, maybe? Inferring the reason for the colour? A good start would be to find out why, their faces are red in the first place, and then hypothesise from there onwards.

Comment: @user19679 That's part of my question. What causes the redness, and does what cause the redness also increase a certain kind neuro connection or hormonal release, etc., that's also correlated with aggressiveness or some other dominant trait.

Comment: @user19679 increased vascularity may be part of it, yes. But from seeing the monkeys at different angles, it looked like more a pigmentation. I was hoping there'd be a wildlife vet (or something along those lines) who could speak to it.